# WCF - if service initialisation fails custom validation, deactivate service

Tags: wcf, service, constructor, activation

how would you best go about the task of deactivating further use of a IIS6 or 7 hosted WCF service based on framework 3.5, when a custom condition is detected.

I thought perhaps that you could create a static constructor in the service implementation (i.e. .svc code behind file) that validates my app settings, should one of the settings be invalid, I could throw an exception. Thinking that the WCF infrastructure would fail to start and so IIS would provide a 401 error (or alike) when browsing the svc file.

I feel this is to easy, im thinking perhaps this is not the right thing to do, perhaps i need to be implementing another WCF interface to plug into some sort of WCF activation logic and signal a no-start. Or something like that?

Any ideas.

Many thanks
Chris

Comment: wow nobody appears to know, usually you get some sort of reply within hours but its been 2 days, bet this is a hard one to crack.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the best place to do this is by creating a custom service factory implementation. Perform the validation before service creation, if it fails then throw an exception there, not in the constructor of the service implementation.